# I don't understand how looping with dir() works vba

Tags: vba, filesystems

I used to use FSO to loop through folders and files in folders. It works well enough and is intuitive, but is considerably slower than using `Dir()`. I can successfully use `Dir()` to loop through folders and files. There are many great example on here and other forums that showed me how.

What I would like to know is WHY finishing off your loop with something like `mydir = Dir()`, returns the next file/folder in the directory? Even though I know how to use the code, I don't like using techniques when I can't explain WHY they work.

I appreciate any explanation you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the internals of `dir` but the principle in general is very simple.
When you call `dir(path)` with a string, dir returns the first (if any) file from that directory (that matches the filter). It also remembers the directory, filter and the position. Any call to `dir` without parameter returns the next element or an empty string.

A simple example to reproduce such behaviour.
Functions can have `Static` variables, ie. variables that persist over multiple calls.

```
Public Function TestFunc(Optional par As Integer = -1) As Variant
    Static x As Integer

    If par <> -1 Then
        x = par
    Else
        x = x - 1
    End If

    If x > 0 Then
        TestFunc = x
    Else
        TestFunc = False
    End If
End Function
```

This test will output the numbers from 5 down to 1.

```
Sub testing()
    Dim v

    v = TestFunc(5)
    While v
        Debug.Print v
        v = TestFunc
    Wend
    Debug.Print "-end-"

End Sub
```

You can step through this sub line by line (F8) to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was asking. I did not know that once dir is given a directory, any subsequent calls of dir with no parameters will return the next item in said directory. I know feel good about using this code.

Comment: in addition to this answer, [the documentation for Dir()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) is very helpful.